# Checking an array of sprites for sprite clicked. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm creating a zombies game in AS3, and I created an array of zombie sprites. Every time a new wave is started it creates a certain amount of zombie sprites based on the wave level. Here is the function to create the zombie sprites.

```
       public function spawnZombies(amount:int):void {
            for (var spawned:int = 0; spawned < amount; spawned++) {
                Stats.zombieAmount += 1;
                zombies.push(new CreateZombie("zombie.png", Math.random()*-(Stats.level * 150), gameHeight - 45));
                addChild(zombies[zombies.length - 1].spriteObj);
                zombies[zombies.length - 1].spriteObj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function killed(evt:MouseEvent):void {
                    Stats.zombieAmount -= 1;
                    Stats.money += 1;
                    moneyText.displayText.text = "$" + Stats.money;
                    trace(zombies.indexOf(evt.currentTarget));
                    removeChild(evt.currentTarget as Sprite);
                    zombies[zombies.indexOf(evt.currentTarget as Sprite)] = null;
                });
            }
        }
```

Now that's all fine and dandy but I'm having a problem with the `eventListiner` I'm adding to every sprite I create. The problem is in these lines of code:

```
trace(zombies.indexOf(evt.currentTarget)); //Returns -1
removeChild(evt.currentTarget as Sprite); //Works fine
zombies[zombies.indexOf(evt.currentTarget as Sprite)] = null; //Sets -1 in list to null, not what I want!
```

The problem is in the finding the index of the sprite using the target, it never seems to find it, and always returns -1; If anyone has any ideas, please help!

Comment: Your inline mouse click handler is going to cause a memory leak.  Each spawned zombie will stay in memory because of it.

Comment: Iterate, I'm not sure I how I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate issue, is that you are storing the `CreateZombie` instances in the `zombies` array, but your click listener is being added to the `spriteObj` which is a property of the CreateZombie instance added to the array.

This means that in your click handler, `evt.currentTarget` is a reference to the `spriteObj`, not the `CreateZombie` instance.   Hence it is not found in the array when you do indexOf.

It looks like there is no reference in the `spriteObj` to the `CreateZombie` object it was spawned from.  So you may have to resort to looping through the entire array trying to find the Zombie that goes with the spriteObj.

```
function getZombieForSprite(spriteObj){
    for(var i:int=0;i<zombies.length;i++){
        if(zombies[i].spriteObj === spriteObj) return zombies[i]; 
    }
    return null;
}
```

If the `spriteObj` is a custom class, then it might be easier to give it a property that references the `CreateZombie` obj it came from.

Or, if CreateZombie is just a factory method as the name would suggest, just store the `spriteObj` in the `zombies` array.

---

Now, as a tip to avoid memory leaks, you should either make your click listener weak: `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler, false, 0, true);` (the last parameter is the weak flag).  Or explicitly remove that event listener when you kill the zombie.   If you don't, that event listener will keep the object in memory even after you've killed it and removed all other references to it.

Comment: Thank's I'll refactor to fix this now!